# Install SQL Server 2012 on ubuntu

Tags: sql, sql-server, ubuntu, sql-server-2012

How can I install SQL Server 2012 on ubuntu?

Comment: did you searching?  https://www.google.com/search?q=how+can+i+install+mssql+server+2012+on+ubuntu%3F&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBF_enAZ759AZ759&ei=iy1mWoy1NMiosAHA4afIAg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=637

Comment: You tagged mysql and sql server but specifically mention sql server in your text. Pick the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

You can't install MSSQL Server 2012 on Ubuntu. It's not on [supported OS list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx#TOP_Principal).

But you *can* install MSSQL Server 2017. [This doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu) has instructions:

> Import the public repository GPG keys:
>
> ```
> wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Register the Microsoft SQL Server Ubuntu
>
> repository:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"
> ```
>
> Note
>
> > This is the Cumulative Update (CU) repository. For more information
> >     about your repository options and their differences, see Change source
> >     repositories.
>
> Run the following commands to install SQL Server:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
> ```
>
> After
>   the package installation finishes, run mssql-conf setup and follow the
>   prompts to set the SA password and choose your edition.
>
> ```
> sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
> ```
>
> Tip
>
> > If you are trying SQL Server 2017 in this tutorial, the following
> >     editions are freely licensed: Evaluation, Developer, and Express.
>
> Note
>
> > Make sure to specify a strong password for the SA account (Minimum
> >     length 8 characters, including uppercase and lowercase letters, base
> >     10 digits and/or non-alphanumeric symbols).
>
> Once the configuration is done, verify that the service is running:
>
> ```
> systemctl status mssql-server
> ```
>
> If you plan to connect remotely,
>   you might also need to open the SQL Server TCP port (default 1433) on
>   your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

To install the mssql-server Package on Ubuntu, follow these steps:
Enter superuser mode. ...
Exit superuser mode. ...
Run the following commands to install SQL Server: `sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server.`
After the package installation finishes, run the configuration script and follow the prompts.

for more details look [Installing SQL on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850957/how-do-i-install-mssql-server-and-or-tools-for-linux-on-16-04)